# Evaluation of integral $\int (R^2+x^2)^{-3/2} dx$ gives a problem

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, physics

So the integral was $$kR^2\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}(R^2+x^2)^{\frac{-3}{2}}dx$$

$$\implies kR^2\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}R^{-3}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{R^2}\right)^{\frac{-3}{2}}dx$$

$$\implies kR^2\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}R^{-3}\left(1+\tan^2\theta\right)^{\frac{-3}{2}}dx$$

$$\implies k\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\left(sec^2\theta\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}d\theta$$
Because
$\cfrac{d \tan \theta} {dx}=\cfrac{1}{R}$ and $\cfrac{d\tan\theta}{d\theta}=1+\cfrac{x^2}{R^2}$
Therefore $dx=R\left(1+\frac{x^2}{R^2}\right)d\theta$

Integral changes to $$k\left[\sin\theta\right]^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}=2$$

But if I change the integral to
$$ k\left[\left(1+\frac{R^2}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\right]^{+\infty}_{-\infty}=0$$

The given answer is 2 in book.

1. **Why is there a difference in the values of integral?**
2. **If above contradiction is not wrong,*why and when to prefer one formula over other?***

Such integrals are used a lot of times in physics (e.g. field due to infinite solenoid, field due to infinite wire.) Does it show a property of calculus often ignored in physics?( you know like we cancel $dx$ in physics though technically wrong)

Comment: The correct value of the integral is 2

Comment: Amuzing is that we can guess the antiderivative without any calculus.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Huh! How's that done? Does that explain the difference in values of integrals?

Comment: The reason you got the wrong value for the integral the second way is because the antiderivative you used isn’t valid. Remember, the antiderivative of an even function should always be an odd function (and vice versa), so that alone should have told you something was wrong.

Comment: See if $2/R^2$ works. Part of your problem is in your limits of integration, along with @DavidH's comment.

Comment: @DavidH But even putting $(1+\cot^2\theta)^{-1/2}$in place of $\sin \theta$ with unchanged limits gives wrong answer. Why is it so when $\sin \theta$ is literally $(1+\cot^2\theta)^{-1/2}$?

Comment: @Aruralreader Put $2/R^2$ where?

Comment: The integral in the title is $2/R^2$.

Comment: @Aurelius Actually, $(1+\cot^2\theta)^{-1/2}=(\csc^2\theta)^{-1/2}=(\sin^2\theta)^{1/2}=|\sin\theta|$, which only equals $\sin\theta$ when it's positive.

Comment: @DavidH When I took $$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}(\sec^2\theta)^{\frac{-1}{2}}d\theta=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}|\cos\theta|$$ it didn't cause problems because $\cos()$ is even function and for that range $\cos\theta=|\cos\theta|$?

Comment: @Aurelius Correct! You can probably look back now and find a similar sign error in your antiderivative where you assumed $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for all real $x$. For reference, here’s the actual antiderivative: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+%28R%5E2+%2B+x%5E2%29%5E%28-3%2F2%29+dx